# How to fire Text Change Event Of Autocomplete Textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Textbox with Autocomplete Feature.
On selection of data from autocomplete list then on Enter `key press` it is firing the
text change event.
But I want to fire the text change event on selection of data.

```
function abc(sender, args) {
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=txtNumber.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/abc") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('^')[0],
                                val: item.split('^')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#<%=hdnNumber.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
                if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                    $("#<%=hdnNumber.ClientID %>").val(-1);
                    document.getElementById('<%=txtNumber.ClientID%>').value = "";
                    return false;
                }

            },
            minLength: 0
        }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });
    });
}
```

Comment: I do have the same problem.

Comment: In case of asp.net, change autopostback(Properties) to true in 'textbox' and in the case of windows, give key press event to the auto complete list instead of textbox.

Comment: @gkrishy:I have already tried to make the autopost back property as true but it did not work.

Comment: Did you tried with ajax autocompleteextender ? If not, show us with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox `KeyDown` event fires with the `keyCode` 13 when you select the autocomplete value.

To detect when the item in the list has been selected you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
        MsgBox("Autocomplete value selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable, try with this line of code.

aspx page :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
                AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txtNumber_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
              <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
MinimumPrefixLength="1"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
TargetControlID="txtNumber"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
```

Code Behind :

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
{
   List<string> customers = new List<string>();
   customers.Add(Your Values); // Your auto complete values
}
```

You can bind database values also. Please let me know, if i confused your mind.

Comment: Maybe it is good to say that the autocompleteextender you are refering to is part of the AjaxControlToolkit.